# RandomizedSearchCV Pipeline select hyperparameters of SelectPercentile using mutual_info_classif

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

## What I have

I have a pipeline that runs with my hyperparameter distributions

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scale', MinMaxScaler()),
    ('vt', VarianceThreshold()),
    ('pca', PCA(random_state=0)),
    ('select', SelectPercentile()),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0))
])

hyper_params0 = {
    'vt__threshold' : stats.distributions.uniform(0, 0.1),
    'pca__n_components' : stats.distributions.uniform(0.8, 0.19),
    'select__percentile' : stats.distributions.randint(1, 101),
    'clf__n_estimators' : stats.distributions.randint(50, 1000),
    'clf__criterion' : ['gini', 'entropy'],
    'clf__min_samples_split' : stats.distributions.uniform(0, 0.1),
    'clf__min_samples_leaf' : stats.distributions.uniform(0, 0.1),
    'clf__max_features' : ['sqrt', 'log2', None],
    'clf__bootstrap' : [True, False],
}

hyper_params=[
    {
        **hyper_params0,
        **{
            'select__score_func' : [mutual_info_classif],
        }
    },
    {
        **hyper_params0,
        **{
            'select__score_func' : [f_classif],
        }
    }
]

rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe,
    param_distributions=hyper_params,
    n_iter=25,
    cv=5,
    scoring='f1_macro',
    n_jobs=-1,
    random_state=0,
    verbose=3
)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

rscv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

## What I want

What I would like to do is search through the `n_neighbors` parameter in the `mutual_info_classif` within `SelectPercentile`.

## What I tried

I tried editing `hyper_params` like so:

```
hyper_params=[
    {
        **hyper_params0,
        **{
            'select__score_func' : [mutual_info_classif],
            'select__score_func__n_neighbors' : stats.distributions.randint(3, 15)
        }
    },
    {
        **hyper_params0,
        **{
            'select__score_func' : [f_classif],
        }
    }
]
```

But I get the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'set_params'`. I followed a loose example on the scikit-learn site [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_compare_reduction.html?highlight=pipeline%20gridsearch) but didn't get very far. Also tried using `'passthrough'` like this:

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scale', MinMaxScaler()),
    ('vt', VarianceThreshold()),
    ('pca', PCA(random_state=0)),
    ('select', 'passthrough'),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0))
])
...
hyper_params=[
    {
        **hyper_params0,
        **{
            'select__score_func' : [SelectPercentile(mutual_info_classif)],
            'select__score_func__n_neighbors' : stats.distributions.randint(3, 15)
        }
    },
    {
        **hyper_params0,
        **{
            'select__score_func' : [SelectPercentile(f_classif)],
        }
    }
]
```

But get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set_params'`.

## Question

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests the `mutual_info_classif` is a function, hence `GridSearchCV` cannot set the parameters for it using `__`. `GridSearchCV` can set the parameter only for the classes which support the `BaseEstimator` design.

First, you need to create a custom `SelectPercentile` that can take the `n_neighbors` as a class parameter.

```
class SelectPercentileMI(SelectPercentile):
    def __init__(self, percentile=10, n_neighbors=3):
        self.n_neighbors=n_neighbors
        super().__init__(percentile=percentile,
                         score_func=partial(mutual_info_classif, n_neighbors=3))
```

Now, your problem is resolved.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, NMF
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2, SelectPercentile, mutual_info_classif, f_classif
from scipy import stats
from functools import partial


pipe = Pipeline([
    ('feature_selector', 'passthrough'),
    ('classify', LinearSVC(dual=False, max_iter=10000))
])

C_OPTIONS = [1, 10]
param_grid = [
    {
        'feature_selector': [SelectPercentile(f_classif)],
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
    {
        'feature_selector': [SelectPercentileMI()],
        'feature_selector__n_neighbors' : [2,3],
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
]

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, n_jobs=1, param_grid=param_grid)
X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
grid.fit(X, y)

grid.best_params_
```

> {'classify__C': 10,
>   'feature_selector': SelectPercentileMI(n_neighbors=3, percentile=10),
>   'feature_selector__n_neighbors': 3}

Comment: Thank you so much! Question, what is `partial` that you use in the class definition?

Comment: Also, how did the grid select `n_neighbors=1` when you provided it `[2,3]`?

Comment: `partial` is a built-in function in python. Refer [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial). It helps in creating a function handle with a specific parameter values.

Comment: you are right, that's a typo. I was trying with different hyper parameters and finally copy pasted wrong one. Updated it now